# Hide/Show Div- Wordpress Category Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have been looking for over 3 hours trying to figure this out so my apologies if you think this has been answered.

I am fully aware how to add a show/hide div to a page but I am struggling to add it to a category page in WP.

My site: http://www.ticketyoda.co.uk/6-nations-tickets

What I require is to be able to have a DIV under each category that can be shown when a button is selected. At present when I select a toggle it hides and then shows all divs on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targeting all divs with the class "flip". You can remedy this by adding `this` to specify that you're only interested in the clicked-on element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".flip").click(function() {
        var target= $(this).next(".panel");
        $(target).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajfarkas/tnb9rh98/1/) of this in action (sorry it's not pretty).

Answer (score 0):

Have some more info.

See here..

http://www.ticketyoda.co.uk/professor-green

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".flip").click(function() {
        $(".panel").slideToggle("");
    });
});
</script>
```

html

```
<style type="text/css">
div.panel {
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-bottom:120px;
padding: 0px;
background: #fff;
border: solid 1px #fff;
}
p.flip {

    margin-top:0px;
margin-left:540px;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding: 0px;
margin-top:-32px;
background: #fff;
border: solid 1px #fff;


}

div.panel {
widht: 50%;
height: 60px;
display: none;
 }
 </style>



<p class="flip"><img src="http://www.ticketyoda.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/ticketview.png" /></p>
```